# how make a show and hide caption for the radio button with picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my design is a radio button with picture. I want put a show and hide description effect. Once the radio button was clicked a certain description should show and if the other radio button was clicked, the description from the previous should hide and then show the description of the current button.

Here is my html codes for the radio buttons with pictures:

`
    Our Ingredients for...

```
<div class="slider">
<!-- Lamb Kebab Pizza -->
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" value="kebab" id="id1" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="id1">
    <img src="../img/kebab.jpg" width="100" alt="Lamb Kebab Pizza" class="img img-responsive" />
    </label>
<img src="../img/kebab.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />


<!-- Fennel Sausage Pizza -->
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" value="fennel" id="id2" />
<label for="id2">
<img src="../img/fennel_copy.jpg" width="100" alt="Fennel Sausage Pizza" class="img img-responsive" />
</label>
<img src="../img/fennel_copy.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />


<!-- Pistachio and Sausage Pizza -->
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" value="pistachio" id="id3" />
<label for="id3">
<img src="../img/pistachio.jpg" width="100" alt="Pistachio and Sausage Pizza" class="img img-responsive" />
</label>
<img src="../img/pistachio.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />


<!-- White Truffle Pizza -->
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" value="white" id="id4" />
<label for="id4">
<img src="../img/white_truffle.jpg" width="100" alt="White Truffle Pizza" class="img img-responsive" />
</label>
<img src="../img/white_truffle.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />


<!-- Surly Pizza -->
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" value="surly" id="id5" />
<label for="id5">
<img src="../img/surly_pizza.jpg" width="100" alt="Surly Pizza" class="img img-responsive" />
</label>
<img src="../img/surly_pizza.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />

</div>
```

```
<!-- Lamb Kebab Pizza -->
<div class="kebab">Kebab</div>

<!-- Fennel Sausage Pizza -->
<div class="fennel">Fennel</div>

<!-- Pistachio and Sausage Pizza -->
<div class="pistachio">Pistachio</div>

<!-- White Truffle Pizza -->
<div class="white">White</div>

<!-- Surly Pizza -->
<div class="surly">Surly</div>
```

`

My javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name$='slide_switch']").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value == 'fennel') {
      $(".fennel").show();
      $(".kebab",".pistachio",".white",".surly").hide();
    }
    else if (value == 'pistachio') {
      $(".pistachio").show();
      $(".kebab",".fennel",".pistachio",".surly").hide();
    }
    else if (value == 'white') {
      $(".white").show();
      $(".kebab",".fennel",".pistachio",".surly").hide();
    }
    else if (value == 'surly') {
      $(".surly").show();
      $(".kebab",".fennel",".pistachio","white").hide();
    }
    });
    $(".kebab").show();
    $(".fennel",".pistachio",".white",".surly").hide();
});
```

Comment: You haven't stated what your problem is.

Comment: i suggest you use json for the all the details. it's easier to load content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("input[name='slide_switch']").click(function () {
    $('img').hide();
    $('[src*="'+this.value+'"]').show();
    $('.common').hide();
    $('.' + this.value).show();
});
```

**Note:** i've added a common class to the elements to shorten the code a bit.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/r51g0m1c/)

Comment: yes that's the way i wanted it to work. however, i want the image to stay.. should i delete the $('img').hide(); ? I apologize I new to jquery.. thats why..

Comment: @florie Yeah just remove it.